# Why is my bison/flex not working as intended?

Tags: c, linux, bison, flex-lexer

I have this homework assignment where I have to transform some input into a particular output. The problem I'm having is that I can only convert the first line into the output I need, the other lines return a "syntax error" error.

Additionally, if I change the lines order, no lines are converted so only one particular line is working.

This is my input file:

**Input.txt**

```
B0102 Bobi 2017/01/16 V8 1, massage 12.50
J1841 Jeco 20.2 2017/01/17 V8 2, Tosse 2, tosquia 22.50
B2232 Bobi 2017/01/17 Tosse 1, Leptospirose 1, bath 30.00, massage 12.50
B1841 Jeco 21.4 2017/01/18 Leptospirose 1, Giardiase 2
```

And this is the output I should obtain:

**Output**

```
Bobi (B0102) paid 2 services/vaccines 22.50
Jeco (J1841) paid 3 services/vaccines 62.50
Bobi (B2232) paid 4 services/vaccines 62.50
Jeco (B1841) paid 2 services/vaccines 30.00
```

If I change the line order in the input file, not even the first line is converted.
However, if the order is as I showed above, this is my output:

```
Bobi (B0102) paid 2 services/vaccines 22.50
syntax error
```

This is my code:

**file.y**

```
%{
    #include "file.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    int yylex();
    int counter = 0;
    int vaccineCost = 10;
%}

%union{
    char* code;
    char* name;
    float value;
    int quantity;
};

%token COMMA WEIGHT DATE SERVICE VACCINE
%token CODE
%token NAME
%token VALUE
%token QUANTITY

%type <name> NAME
%type <code> CODE
%type <value> VALUE
%type <quantity> QUANTITY
%type <value> services


%start begining

%%

begining: /*empty*/
    | animal
    ;

animal: CODE NAME WEIGHT DATE services {printf("%s (%s) paid %d services/vaccines %.2f\n", $2, $1, counter, $5); counter = 0;}
    | CODE NAME DATE services {printf("%s (%s) paid %d services/vaccines %.2f\n", $2, $1, counter, $4); counter = 0;}
    ;

services: services COMMA SERVICE VALUE {$$ = $1 + $4; counter++;}
    | services COMMA VACCINE QUANTITY{$$ = $1 + $4*vaccineCost;counter++;}
    | SERVICE VALUE{$$ = $2;counter++;}
    | VACCINE VALUE 
{$$ = $2*vaccineCost;counter++;}
    ;

%%

int main(){
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}

void yyerror (char const *s) {
    fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
}
```

**file.flex**

```
%option noyywrap

%{
    #include "file.h"
    #include "file.tab.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
%}

/*Patterns*/
YEAR 20[0-9]{2}
MONTH 0[1-9]|1[0-2]
DAY 0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]

%%
,                                   {return COMMA,;}
[A-Z][0-9]{4}            {yylval.code = strdup(yytext); return CODE;}       
[A-Z][a-z]*          {yylval.name = strdup(yytext); return NAME;}
[0-9]+[.][0-9]                             {return WEIGHT;}
{YEAR}"/"{MONTH}"/"{DAY}                           {return DATE;}
(banho|massagem|tosquia)                    {return SERVICE;}
[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}              {yylval.value = atof(yytext);return VALUE;}
(V8|V10|Anti-Rabatica|Giardiase|Tosse|Leptospirose)          {return VACCINE;}
[1-9]           {yylval.quantity = atoi(yytext);return QUANTITY;}
\n  
.       
<<EOF>> return 0;

%%
```

And these are the commands I execute:

```
bison -d file.y
flex -o file.c file.flex
gcc file.tab.c file.c -o exec -lfl
./exec < Input.txt
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me what is wrong with my code?

Thanks and if I my explaination wasn't good enough I'll try my best to explain it better!!

Comment: Please add `%define parse.error verbose` to the top of your bison file to enable better error messages and then post the expanded syntax error message you get with that option. Also please consider translating your token and non-terminal names to English to make it easier to understand your code.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll translate....
I added that line you said and I got this output: `syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting $end
`

Comment: Instead of translating `VIRGULA` to `COMMA`, consider using `','`, which doesn't require translation and is much clearer.

Comment: And what about the flex file? Do I delete the COMMA entry or leave it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two different problems which cause those symptoms.

1. Your top-level grammar only accepts at most a single `animal`:

   ```
   inicio: /*vazio*/
       | animal
   ```

   So an input containing more than one line won't be allowed. You need a top-level which accepts any number of `animal`s. (By the way, modern bison versions let you write `%empty` as the right-hand side of an empty production, instead of having to (mis)use a comment.
2. The order of your scanner rules means that most of the words you want to recognise as `VACINA` will instead be recognised as `NOME`. Recall that when two patterns match the same token, the first one in the file wlll win. So with these rules:

   ```
   [A-Z][a-z]*          {yylval.nome = strdup(yytext); return NOME;}
   (V8|V10|Anti-Rabatica|Giardiase|Tosse|Leptospirose)          {return VACINA;}
   ```

   Tokens like `Tosse`, which could match either rule, will be assumed to match the first rule. Only V8 and Anti-Rabatical, which `[A-Z][a-z]*` doesn't match, will fall through to the second rule. So your first input line doesn't trigger this problem, but all the other ones do.

You probably should handle newline characters syntactically, unless you allow treatment records to be split over multiple lines. And be aware that many (f)lex versions do not allow empty actions, as in your last two flex rules. This may cause lexical errors.

And finally

```
<<EOF>> return 0;
```

is unnecessary. That's how the scanner handles end-of-fike by default. `<<EOF>>` rules are often wring or redundant, and should only be used when clearly needed (and with great care).

Comment: 1. If I do `begining: | begining '\n' animal` will I achieve it?

Comment: 2. I understand my mistake, I'll fix it and post the results... Thanks for the response!!

Comment: I got it working! All thanks to you!! Thank you for the answer :)